# Flask - render template destroys dynamically generated html from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a basic input form on html, where a button dynamically creates more input boxes with javascript.

Upon pressing submit the data is collected in python (flask) fine, however upon returning the response and static html page the extra dynamic input boxes created are destroyed.

What is the best way to render template, or return a variables to the html page, without destroying the dynamically created boxes.

Thankyou

```
***HTML:***
<div class="col-12" id = "InputRows">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 offset-xl-0"><label for="Quantity">Quantity</label></div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 offset-xl-1"><input type="number" name="Quantity" value = {{QuantityReturn}} required></div>
    
    
  # New inputs are dynamically appended here
  </div>

***Python:***
@app.route("/CalculateMaths", methods=['POST'])
def CalculateMaths():
    if request.method=='POST':
        Quantity=request.form.get("Quantity")
        QuantityReturn=Quantity 

    return render_template("template.html",QuantityReturn=Quantity) #sending back this destroys the dynamically appended HTML inputs
```

Comment: If you're doing a whole page refresh, you'd have to pass and repopulate any values the user has entered. Probably better is to use AJAX/JS to add the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The `render_template` method, as the name suggests, re-renders the entire page. This is why it is deleting any changes you made to the DOM dynamically. You are probably better off preventing the default submit event using a client-side script and simply requesting/returning the quantity in JSON format.